# Can't access CakePHP fixture db when triggering test with Travis CI

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, travis-ci

so I have a project in CakePHP. When pushing my code, Travis CI should run my test. My Test is named ToolTest and its Fixture is ToolFixture.
My .travis.yml looks as following:

```
language: php

php: 5.3

services:
- mysql

before_script:
- sh -c "mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE test;'" 
- chmod -R 777  project/tmp
- echo "<?php
  class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public \$test = array(
      'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
      'persistent' => false,
      'database' => 'test',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'login' => 'travis'
    );
  }" > project/database.php

script:
sudo project/Console/cake test app Model/Tool --stderr
```

The error strack trace on travis says:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MissingConnectionException' with message 'Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.' in /home/travis/build/project/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php:194
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
```

I already tried '127.0.0.1' instead of localhost, same error messages. When running my test on the VM, the test passes.
What I've noticed:
If I'm not running the script command, travis is successful, so creating the db test and writing the database.php should work fine, right?

My test and fixture are pretty minimalistic.
ToolTest:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->Tool = ClassRegistry::init('Tool');
}

public function testFindListById()
{
    $result = $this->Tool->findListById(2);
    $expected = array(
      2 => 'Java'

    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```

ToolFixture:

```
class ToolFixture extends CakeTestFixture
{
public $useDbConfig = 'test';
public $fields = array(
    'id' => 'string',
    'name' => 'string'
);    

public $records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'HTML'

    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Java'

    )
  );
}
```

What am I missing? I've been stuck with this problem for days..Any ideas? Glad for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that I didn't write my database config in the correct folder..
Instead of

```
>project/database.php
```

It should have been

```
> project/Config/database.php
```

Jeez..